# XML Serializer - Deserializing an XML array

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have the following sample XML:

```
<PossibleAddresses>
    <Address tempid="12345">1 The Street England</Address>
    <Address tempid="6789">2 The Street England</Address>
    <Address tempid="4321">3 The Street England</Address>
    <Address tempid="1111">4 The Street England</Address>
</PossibleAddresses>
```

I am trying to deserialize this XML so that I essentially just get back a list of 'Address' objects that contains two properties. One being the 'tempid' the other being the actual address string itself.

My class looked something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("PossibleAddresses")]
    public class Addresses
    {
        [XmlArrayItem("Address", Type = typeof(Address))]
        public List<Address> PossibleAddresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tempid")]
        public string TempId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

I am then using the XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML. With T being the class 'Addresses':

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string data)
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(data));
        }
```

Currently this will deserialize successfully. I just end up with an empty list of addresses.

Comment: You'll also need to change the decoration of `PossibleAddresses ` to `[XmlElement("Address", Type = typeof(Address))]public List<Address> PossibleAddresses { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FullAddress` here should be with attribute `XmlText`

```
[XmlText]
public string FullAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

GoogleHireMe is correct that you need an `XmlText` attribute.

```
public class Address
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tempid")]
    public string TempId { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
}
```

However, you can deserialize the addresses directly as an array:

```
var serializer =
    new XmlSerializer(
        typeof(Address[]),
        new XmlRootAttribute("PossibleAddresses"));
Address[] items;

using(var stream = new StringReader(xml))
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    items = (Address[]) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```